# Integrate with RBS WorldPay Hosted Payment Page (XML Redirect) using Python

Tags: python, payment-gateway, payment, worldpay

Does anyone have any example code for integrating with [RBS WorldPay](http://www.rbsworldpay.com/support/kb/gg/pdf/rxml.pdf) using Python?  Specifically posting the XML order to WorldPay

Answer (score 1):

It's an HTTP POST with Basic Authentication. Basic Authentication is described in the official [Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2 HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html). So, where XML is the XML you're sending, URL is the URL you're posting to, and MERCHANT_CODE and PASSWORD are self explanatory, the following works:

```
import urllib2
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, URL, MERCHANT_CODE, PASSWORD)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
request = Request(URL, XML, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
response = opener.open(request, XML)

# do something with the response

response.close()
```